# storage buffer and wrongfully aligned data

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm giving some materials to my storage buffer so that my shader can have the materials of the objects I'm trying to draw, but the colors do no correspond, I think it's due to memory alignment but I'm new to opengl so I don't find the error

```cpp
struct Material
{
    Color diffuse;
    Color specular;
    Color emission;
    float ns;

    Material( ) : diffuse(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f), specular(Black()), emission(), ns(0) {}
};
struct Color
{
    float r, g, b, a;
};
```

and my fragment shader

```c
struct Material
{
    vec4 diffuse;
    vec4 specular;
    vec4 emission;
    float ns;
};

layout(binding=1) readonly buffer IndexBlock{
    uint color_indices[];
};

layout(binding=2) readonly buffer MaterialBlock {
    Material materials[];
};
```

in the main :

```c
uint color_index = color_indices[gl_PrimitiveID];
vec3 frag_color = materials[color_index].diffuse.xyz;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to use `std140` or `std430` [layout qualifier](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_(GLSL)).

See [OpenGL 4.6 API Core Profile Specification; 7.6.2.2 Standard Uniform Block Layout](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf#page=168&zoom=100,0,381):

[...]

> 9. If the member is a structure, the base alignment of the structure is N, where
>      N is the largest base alignment value of any of its members, [...]
> 10. If the member is an array of S structures, the S elements of the array are laid out in order, according to rule (9).

You can add 3 floats to the c++ structure. But it It would be better to use an [alignas specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas) and align the structure to 16 bytes:

```cpp
struct alignas(16) Material
{
    Color    diffuse;
    Color    specular;
    Color    emission;
    float    ns;

    // [...]
}
```

Shader:

```c
struct Material
{
    vec4 diffuse;
    vec4 specular;
    vec4 emission;
    float ns;
};

layout(binding=1, std430) readonly buffer IndexBlock{
    uint color_indices[];
};

layout(binding=2, std430) readonly buffer MaterialBlock {
    Material materials[];
};
```

The difference between `std140` and `std430` is, that for `std140` the base alignment and stride of arrays of scalars and vectors and of structures is rounded up to a multiple of the base alignment of a `vec4`. This is not the case for `std430`.

Comment: *"Add 3 floats to the c++ structure*" It would be better to use `alignas(16)` instead of manually padding like that in this case. Especially if you're unsure of your ABI's alignment rules.

Answer (score 0):

You can test if `Color` matches `vec4` easily.

```
std::cout<< sizeof(Color) <<std::endl;
std::cout<< sizeof(vec4) <<std::endl;
```

if the sizes are different then you can stop here.

if the sizes are equal, then try to init the same values for `Color` and `vec4`

```
Color c(1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0);
vec4  v(1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0);
unsigned char buf1[sizeof(Color)];
unsigned char buf2[sizeof(vec4)];
memcpy(buf1, &c, sizeof(Color));
memcpy(buf2, &v, sizeof(vec4));
bool equal = (memcmp(buf1, buf2, sizeof(Color)) == 0);
std::cout<< "Is equal? " << equal ? "yes" : "no" <<std::endl;
```

BTW: I think vec4 uses `double`, not `float`.

Comment: This is not c/c++ it is [OpenGL Shading Language (GLSL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_Shading_Language). The code is executed on the GPU